# PHP Convert 256 Colors to 16 Colors

Tags: php, colors, hex

I need to convert results of 256 Hex colors to related 16 Hex colors. For example, if I have a result of a #3399CC, it would be converted to a basic blue color #000099.

Comment: Great that's very colorful, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807669/how-to-convert-an-rgb-color-to-the-closest-matching-8-bit-color

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, the link above is close but not going to give you the actual color that is in the same "family". Any other suggestions are very appreciated!